# Issues with Running Ansible Playbook on Linux T2 Instance Localhost

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to figure out why my Ansible playbook is not working. I have tried 20 different ways of indenting the playbook but it is not working.

I am currently launching an Amazon Linux t2 instance and then installing ansible using following commands:

```
sudo yum update -y
sudo amazon-linux-extras install ansible2 -y
```

Then I create a playbook *first.yml* using *"vim first.yml"* , and the playbook looks like this:

```
---
- name: update web servers
  hosts: localhost 
  remote_user: root

  tasks:
  - name: ensure apache is at the latest version
    yum:
      name: httpd
      state: latest
```

I run playbook using *"ansible-playbook first.yml"* and get the following error:

> ERROR! We were unable to read either as JSON nor YAML, these are the
> errors we got from each: JSON: No JSON object could be decoded
>
> Syntax Error while loading YAML.   mapping values are not allowed in
> this context
>
> The error appears to be in '/home/ec2-user/first.yml': line 7, column
> 8, but may be elsewhere in the file depending on the exact syntax
> problem.
>
> The offending line appears to be:
>
> tasks:
> ^ here

I would appreciate any help, thank you !

Comment: Is this the verbatim content of your playbook `first.yml`? What is the version of ansible (`ansible --version`)?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what th eplaybook is word for word. Ansible version is 2.9.13 and Python version is 2.7.18

Comment: No mix of tabs and spaces? Really weird as your code looks legit.